# Resize textField Based On Content

Tags: ios, swift, resize, textfield

How can a textField be resized based on content while using auto-layout in an iOS application written in Swift?

The text field will resize as necessary to fit its content when the view loads as well as while the user is typing.

Ideally, the text field would stop resizing at a certain point, say, 6 lines, and become scrollable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to use an `UITextView` instead of an `UITextField`.

Then, you can use the `sizeThatFits` method.

But first you have to know how high one line will be. You can get that information by using `lineHeight`:

```
var amountOfLinesToBeShown: CGFloat = 6
var maxHeight: CGFloat = yourTextview.font.lineHeight * amountOfLinesToBeShown
```

After that, just call the `sizeThatFits` method inside your `viewDidLoad` method and set the maxHeight (`line * 6`) as your textview height:

```
yourTextview.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(yourTextview.frame.size.width, maxHeight))
```

Comment: Why do you use 2 times the `yourTextview.sizeThatFits(…)`?

Comment: is there any way we can increase the number of lines of a UITextField? @Christian

Comment: @ManuGupta No. You have to use an `UITextView` if you want the multiline-feature.

Comment: i did all inside viewdidload but my textfield didn't increase.let amountOfLinesToBeShown:CGFloat = 4
    let maxHeight:CGFloat = textView.font!.lineHeight * amountOfLinesToBeShown
    textView.sizeToFit()
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(textView.frame.size.width, maxHeight))
i want  to increase my textview according to size of content and must not be greater than certain height.

Comment: I used this method But in CGSizeMake I got Error so I Changed this to CGSize.init And Run success But the problem is that text view still has just two lines to be shown! @Christian

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
var textView : UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textView = UITextView()
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.size.width, height: textView.frame.size.height))
}
```