# TextField automatic resizing while typing in Swift using Auto-layout

Tags: swift, resize, autolayout, textfield

I need to set up a TextField that automatically changes its width while typing.
I though it was a simple task, but its turning out to be pretty challenging.

If I disable auto-layout, all I have to do to achieve this is to change the width of the TextField every time a new character is typed, using the following line:

```
TextField.frame.size.height = 30 + counter
```

(counter is related to the number of characters in the TextField).

Using auto-layout, this procedure doesn't work anymore.
Does anybody have a solution to this problem?
I haven't found a proper answer anywhere!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think auto-layout added a constant "Width Equals" constraint to your text field.  Try removing it and see if that works.  Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

You've to use `UITextView` for this and use it's `sizeThatFits` method. More info about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389913/resize-textfield-based-on-content)

Comment: Please select the answer,If I helped.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am pretty sure there is a way to do the same thing using a UITextField instead of a UITextView

Comment: Actually you can have a multi-line UiTextField. Read the answer on this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345561/how-to-create-a-multiline-uitextfield)

Comment: No, sorry, I didn't make myself clear. I I don't want a multi-line textfield (I have to write numbers, so it have to be on the same line), I want it to be single-line and to auto-adjust its width while typing.