# how to make autoresize textfield in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I need to set up a TextField that automatically changes its width while typing. The size of textfield should change dynamically.
I found the following solution but not getting how to use it exactly
[Resize textField Based On Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389913/resize-textfield-based-on-content)

Answer (score -1):

You have to use `UITextView` for this and use it's `sizeThatFits` method.

First you have to know how high line will go

```
var totalLines:CGFloat = 5
var maxHeight:CGFloat = myTextview.font.lineHeight * totalLines
```

Then in your `viewDidLoad` method

```
myTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(myTextview.frame.size.width, maxHeight))
```

You are doing wrong in your code. use this above code in `viewDidLoad`

```
 @IBOutlet weak var myTextview: UITextView!



    override func viewDidLoad()


    { super.viewDidLoad()
        let totalLines:CGFloat = 5

        let maxHeight:CGFloat = (myTextview.font!.lineHeight * totalLines)



        myTextview.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(myTextview.frame.size.width, maxHeight))

}

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning() // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated. } }

}
```

Comment: Compilation fails with the message " Instance member 'myTextview' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'". Not getting how to resolve it?

Comment: here use your textfield name. I have used it mytextfield as an example @dimple

Comment: ya...i used my textview name...I have set outlet for textview with "myTextview" name

Comment: @dimple could you please share your viewController code here

Comment: import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myTextview: UITextView!
    var totalLines:CGFloat = 5
    var maxHeight:CGFloat = (myTextview.font.lineHeight * totalLines)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      myTextView.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(myTextview.frame.size.width, maxHeight))
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}

Comment: i got answer here ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34605939/instance-member-mytextview-cannot-be-used-on-type-viewcontroller/34606327#34606327...thanks  But textfield is not autoresize during typeing..ie above code is not working as i desire

Comment: @dimple you were doing it wrong. Please check my updated answer and mark it correct if it solves your problem

Comment: @ hellosheikh..i have used your updated code but still my textview is not autoresizing during typing

Comment: @dimple  did answer here work for you .stackoverflow.com/questions/34605939/   ?

Comment: ..No stackoverflow.com/questions/34605939/   this answer is also not working for me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99775/discussion-between-hellosheikh-and-dimple).