# how to make autoresize textfield, who adjust size with text input in swift

Tags: swift2

How can a textField be resized based on content while using auto-layout in an iOS application written in Swift?

The text field will resize as necessary to fit its content when the view loads as well as while the user is typing. I referred the following link [Resize textField Based On Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389913/resize-textfield-based-on-content)

but it is not making the field autoresize during typing

Comment: If you have clearly referred to the linked mentioned in the question then the answer suggests then you need to use `UITextView` instead of `UITextField`.

Comment: yes , I have used textview as mentioned in the link..but it is not working as I want..this is my codeclass ViewController: UIViewController {

   @IBOutlet weak var myTextview: UITextView!
   var totalLines:CGFloat = 5
   var maxHeight:CGFloat?

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      maxHeight = (myTextview.font!.lineHeight * totalLines)
      myTextview.sizeThatFits(CGSizeMake(myTextview.frame.size.width, maxHeight!))
   }

   override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
      super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
   
   }
}

Answer (score 0):

If you have clearly referred to the linked mentioned in the question then the answer suggests then you need to use `UITextView` instead of `UITextField`.

Well, you can increase the height of `UITextView` using constraints or you can use this library:

https://github.com/ingridwarrior2901/TextViewAutoHeight-Swift