# TextField with multiline in alternative to TextArea?

Tags: ios, javafx, textarea, textfield

I have graphic problem with TextArea in IOS: when I change the page of my app the component TextArea stay fixed  in exposition, is a way to make TextField multiline in order to use it alternatively?
Thank you.

Comment: First of all `TextField ` never be multi lined so use `textview`. and second thing, if you'r asking question then give details about your question because we can't understand your requirement with a single line, as it depends of your question level. If you don't ask question properly then your post will downvoted by many users and promoted to be close.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy sorry I edited now my question

Comment: @BoHalim I can't solve with css, I explain better the problem: when I change the page of my app the component TextArea stay fixed in exposition and doesn't disappear.

Comment: Use textView it is already a multilined.

Comment: @Denise What do you mean by --> **use it alternatively** ??

Comment: I'm using JavaFx abnd the javafxmobile plugin, I didn't have it .

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy use TextField or another component for multiline in alternative to TextArea.

Comment: @Denise Still not getting you. Sorry.

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy I try to explain better:  I want to use a text component that implements multiline instead TextArea. I can't use textview on javafx.

Comment: @Denise And textfieid can''t be multi line.

Comment: It might helps you [textfield-based-on-content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389913/resize-textfield-based-on-content)

Comment: @the_dahiya_boy Please read the tags on the question. This is a question about JavaFX.