# how to increase the height of the textfield according to text

Tags: swift, autolayout, uitextfield, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout

[image]

Here am using two textfields(pickup location, delivery location) in inside a view.

By clicking on any of the textfield am navigating to google autocomplete and getting some text from there, and showing the same in my textfields

here i want to increase the height of the textfield according to text and it should increase the height of the view also.

how should i achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389913/resize-textfield-based-on-content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize textField Based On Content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28389913/resize-textfield-based-on-content)