# How can i create a dynamic textfield programatically

Tags: ios, swift, dynamic, uitextfield, xcode8

I want to add a dynamic textfield when a user clicks somewhere on the view.textfield should increase the size as the user types. Currently i am using the below code

```
textfield = UITextField(frame: rect)
            textfield.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            textfield.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
            textfield.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
            textfield.textColor = UIColor.blue
            textfield.textAlignment = .right
            textfield.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
            textfield.delegate = self
            textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
```

But this textfield is not automatically increasing height and width.

Comment: You may need to use `UITextView` instead of `UITextField`

Comment: I tried with uitextview also, used the same method with textview. But still its not increasing size

Comment: Check this link explanation.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28390016/8687925

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITextViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textView.delegate = self 
    }

   func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

       let ff = textView.text! as NSString

       let rr = ff.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17)])

       textView.frame = CGRect(origin: textView.frame.origin, size: rr)
   }

}
```

//

Arabic

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {

    let ff = textView.text! as NSString

   let rr = ff.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17)!])

    textView.frame = CGRect(origin:CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width - rr.width, y: textView.frame.origin.y), size: rr)

 }
```

[image]

Comment: there should be one static and one variable , it does not make sense that the text expands in both directions

Comment: there should be one static and one variable , it does not make sense that the text expands in both directions

Comment: actually when u user types, width of the textview must increase . when the press "enter" typing must start from next line. this is what i am looking for

Comment: let rr = ff.size(withAttributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font:UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17)!]). This  line is showing errors

Comment: it compiles with me try again , xcode , swift version ??

Comment: Incorrect argument label in call (have 'withAttributes:', expected 'attributes:') I am getting this error

Comment: working fine. thank you. I have one more issue. i have to. increase width towards left as i am using "arabic" language. How can i achieve this

Comment: first it's supposed that you will place it at the right , then content increases from right to left , see edit .....

Comment: this is halfway there, but textview is going to the right end of the screen automatically when we start typing

Comment: it has to be placed where the user clicks

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps to work.

1. create UITextView on clicking on the view as you are creating
   UITextField now.
2. set delegate and implement the delegate method(s) like 'textViewDidChange' or 'UITextViewTextDidChange'notification to get the callback when text changes.
3. inside the callback method set the UITextView frame width and height
   to its content size property's width and height ! happy coding !

If need more help do let me know.

Comment: I tried this code. func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
        textView.frame = CGRect(origin: textView.frame.origin, size: textView.contentSize)
    } But only the height is increasing, not the width. I need both

Comment: what is your initial width for the UITextView ? see contentSize calculation is based on the width you provide initially to the UITextView. So basically width is fixed and contentSize gives you the required height. To achieve what you want, you have to calculate the text width programmatically, then you must have a max width value,so now if the width increases the max width then fix the UITextView width and just increase the height what you get from contentSize property.